# Emacs don't display any colors at all

Tags: colors

The dark blue color on my terminal emulator is hard to read.

Does emacs have the ability to completely disable colors in its output, regardless of whether the colors are used for underlining file names or are part of the prompt of `M-x`?

I've tried using

```
(global-font-lock-mode 0)
```

and the equivalent

```
(setq-default global-font-lock-mode nil)
```

but that just disables applying colors to keywords and bits of syntax in the buffer text itself.

Comment: It may behoove you to place your cursor on the dark blue color and type `C-u C-x =` and see what is there in terms of text properties and overlays.  You can also type `M-x customize-face` to change *most* colors once you know the name of the face, and you can make it whatever color you want, e.g, white foreground / black background.  Your question, as is, essentially says:  you never want font-lock, you never want text-properties, and you never want overlays.  You want to break Emacs ... which I am sure is possible, but there are better ways to go about dealing with undesired colors.

Comment: (Assuming unix) If your terminal variable `TERM` is `xterm-color` or `xterm-256color` you might try setting it to `xterm` just while running emacs: `TERM=xterm emacs -nw` or maybe `vt100`.

Comment: In your `.emacs`: `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(tty-color-mode . -1))`